# Visual Studio 2008 SSIS Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, ssis, 64-bit

I have recently switched from SQL Server 2008 R2, to SQL Server 2008 SP1.  This seems to have caused an issue when I attempt to open an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2008.  I get the error message:

> 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackageSigning100' from assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

I am running a Windows 7 64 bit OS.

I have attempted a re-install of SQL Server which was unsuccessful.

Comment: Did you every get any solution to this? Stuck with the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and you have to do a very through job of removing and installing SQL 2008

Please see this link before you give up.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/5ac7423a-9d7b-4def-b16b-9b4fc188871b